# Will SEO be affected by hiding content through jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

I'm working on a support documentation web app template. A lot of the content is hidden, but I was wanting to boost my SEO with lot's of descriptions of the content. The descriptions would be displayed with a mouseover event and then hidden with a mouseout event. With a click event the actual documentation would appear. All of the content is on one page.

A majority of the content is going to be hidden at any given time. Is this going to affect my SEO negatively?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably best to ask on seo.stackexchange

Comment: Search engines do not disclose their algorithms to prevent abuse, so any answers would be speculation. However, I imagine how you hide them might make a difference. You might try: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks remus, I wasnt aware of that site. I'll look it up and ask my question there as well :)

Comment: `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, `transform: scale(0,0)`, `position: fixed; left: -9999px; top: -9999px;`, `width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden`, `clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px)`... The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. (It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se]; but there it’s probably a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, hiding content will affect SEO, but how exactly is not disclosed, as Alexander mentioned. Google, for instance, devalues some hidden content.

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsW8E4dOtRY) and [this blog post](http://www.freshegg.co.uk/blog/technical-seo/google/how-does-google-treat-hidden-content) for more info.

Comment: Awesome! That video answered my question.